# ORA-21560: argument 2 is null, invalid, or out of range

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
create table test_clob
(
    id number,
    text clob
);

insert into test_clob values
(2,'Hi This can be a value that is too much old');

select * from test_clob;

SET serveroutput ON;
DECLARE
  vlength pls_integer;
  text_cbl CLOB;
  Var_temp1 VARCHAR2(1024);
  starti    number := 1;
  offset number:= 1;
  val pls_integer;
  amt pls_integer := 0;
BEGIN
  SELECT text INTO text_cbl FROM test_clob WHERE id = 2;
  vlength     := SYS.DBMS_lob.getlength(text_cbl);
  WHILE(starti < vlength)
  LOOP
      val := sys.dbms_lob.instr(text_cbl,chr(32),offset);
      amt := val - offset;
      sys.dbms_lob.read(text_cbl,amt,starti,Var_temp1);
      dbms_output.put_line(Var_temp1);
      offset := val;
      starti := val + 1;
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: i am trying to extract each word from the clob type field  using the dbms_lob package functions and procedures.

Comment: What is unclear with the error message? Also, please post the complete error message, so that people can know where the error occurs

Comment: ORA-21560: argument 2 is null, invalid, or out of range ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_LOB", line 1081
ORA-06512: at line 16
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SQL", line 1721

Comment: Try to debug your code without calling the procedure that gives error, but simply spooling your variables; this will help you to understand the issue. I guess you may have a never-ending loop here

Comment: i changed the code to

Answer (score 0):

In some point there will be end of line or text where there will be no space ch ( 32) so in that point it is returning val <=  0 so val - offset returning a negative value to amt so sys.dbms_lob. read with out of range offset value. Keep a check of end of line or text, or you can put and if condition like if val> offset then read.

Comment: could you please elaborate a bit or mark where i can change the code.

Comment: actually the first word comes out fine and then it fails

Comment: Thanks it seems to be working i put in the if to check the condition and also changed the position of the space to be searched .It works fine

Comment: I am putting a part of the code where to change                          
WHILE(starti < vlength)
  LOOP
      val := sys.dbms_lob.instr(text_cbl,chr(32),offset);
      if val - offset > 0 then
        amt := val - offset;
        sys.dbms_lob.read(text_cbl,amt,starti,Var_temp1);
        dbms_output.put_line(Var_temp1);
        offset := val;
        starti := val + 1;
     end if;
  END LOOP;

This might help you

Comment: Please do not use comments to clarify an answer, but write everything useful in the answer. This will make the answer better ( and will lead to upvotes :) )